# Customize SharePoint 2013 New Form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jquery, newform

I am struggling with SharePoint and JQuery.

I tried to add new HTML elements to a a SP 2013 New form. So I fired following command in the Chrome dev console:

`$("select[title='TEST']").closest("td").after("<td>test</td>");`.

Well, SharePoint render the query as: `"<td>test</td>"` and not as `<td>test</td>`.

Do you have a idea?

Comment: Sorry what is the problem? Does it render a plain text instead of html? I have tried and it added word 'test' as expected.

Comment: @Raf: yes, exactly

Comment: I have tried to use your code and it works properly for me.

Comment: I think it is Chrome or jquery issue. Not SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to do :

1. Try to work in another Browser
2. Review your jQuery
3. try to use '' instead of ""
4. If not, try to do some control to skip the quotes ""

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to a script editor web part in newform page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("select[title='TEST']").closest("td").after("<td>test</td>");
})
</script>
```

Or using the following line of code.

```
$("select[title='TEST']").closest("tr").append("<td>test</td>");
```